# Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: memcache

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7, memcache

I just patched magento 1.9.3.6 to support php7.2. Now we are not able to login.

**Here's the error:**

```
Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: memcache (path: unix:///var/run/memcached-multi/site.com_sessions.sock?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10)  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 134
```

**Pls advice. 
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

> **app/etc/env.php file.**

**Modify this section as follows:**

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'memcached',
    'save_path' => '127.0.0.1:11211'
  ],
```

> Change the file **app/etc/local.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        ...
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
        <session_save_path>
            <![CDATA[/tmp/session]]>
        </session_save_path>
     </global>
     ...
</config>
```

Clear your cache and restart apache

```
sudo rm -R var/cache/* var/session/*
sudo rm -R var/session
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I've already tried it. and its working. However if we change the value from <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save> to <session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save> the error comes out.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thanks, @RkRathod . I've already fixed the issue.

Comment: please attache your solution

Comment: fixed it using the solution here https://serverfault.com/questions/916129/php-7-2-failed-to-read-session-data-memcache